# Java numbers with radix > Character.MAX_RADIX

Tags: java, tostring, radix

I have a five-character String and I want to use those five characters as an ASCII-encoded (printable) number. The simplest way to achieve this is to use

```
Long.toString(number, Character.MAX_RADIX);
```

This will give me numbers from `"0"` to `"zzzzz"`. Unfortunately `Long.toString(int, int)` only supports lower-case letters, no upper-case letters. This means that the max radix is `36` and the highest number I can encode is `36^5 - 1 = 60 466 175`. If I could use both lower **and** upper-case letters, I'd get a max radix of `62` and the highest encodable number is `62^5 - 1 = 916 132 831`.

Apart from copying `Long`'s source code and extending the possible digits, is there any other place I should look into, first, where this is already implemented?

Comment: You might want to look for Base64 encoders and decoders (e.g., http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), which use two additional symbols for encoding.

Comment: @subsub: see WhiteFang's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify whether or not the characters need to be **printable** ASCII:

- If they do, then you can go to `95^5`.  There are 95 printable ASCII characters from space (SP) to tilde (~).
- If they don't, then you can go to `128^5` == `2^35`.

Either way, the algorithm for doing the conversion is straightforward, and is simpler than an extension to `Long.toString(...)`.  (You presumably don't have to worry about signs, range errors, or holes in the character `<->` digit mapping.  It would be easier to code this from scratch.)

However, I'm not aware of any *existing* implementation of extended radix numbers.

Comment: They need to be "**printable**". I'll update the question, thanks. Apart from `[0-9a-zA-Z]` some special characters would be OK, too (such as `/`, `-`, `_`, etc)

Comment: thanks for the update. I know it's straightforward. I can copy it from `java.lang.Long`. I was just wondering if I overlooked something where `Character.MAX_RADIX` is not the limit...

Comment: @LukasEder ICU is the place where you would expect the implementation to exist. The ticket is currently sitting in accepted status so now's the time to get the requirements in.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to go two characters beyond alphanumeric you could use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

Using [`Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) you could get 1073741824 possible values like this:

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[4];
bytes[0] = (byte) ((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
bytes[1] = (byte) ((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
bytes[2] = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
bytes[3] = (byte) (value & 0xFF);
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes).substring(1, 6);
```

Comment: Good idea. But the trailing `=` and `==` won't use up extra space? Apart from that, I didn't consider it, because the transformation goes from `byte[]` to `String`, not from `Number` to `String`. But I could handle the extra "encoding" from `Number` to `byte[]`

Comment: You could avoid the trailing `=` by using 3 bytes of an `int`. That would give you an even 24 bits to be encoded into 4 characters.

Comment: 3 bytes is not enough: `256^3 - 1 = 16 777 215`, which is less than my original solution where I get `60 466 175` encodable values

Comment: Oops, somehow the magnitude of your number didn't register and I blindly turned 5 characters into 4 for you :) I updated the answer with a way to get more. For 4 bytes you can safely trim the trailing `==`. And then also remove the first character that'll be the bits from the `int` that just won't fit into your 5 characters.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That sounds more complicated to me than copying `Long.toString(int, int)` and adding a couple of allowed digits to the algorithm. :-) Besides, I don't understand the base64 algorithm well enough to be sure that trimming will not accidentally create "collisions", i.e. several numbers being encoded to the same value, which would be fatal in my case.